# SSRS - Express addition 2014 issues

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've downloaded SSRS 2014 (ExpressAdv 32BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe) and I've found the SQL reporting services configuration manager but I can't find how to launch SSRS to build reports?

I'm probably missing something very obvious so apologies for basic question.

I can query in my management studio fine and the connection to the studio is good in the configuration manager.

Any help as always much appreciated.

Image below of everything downloaded.

[image: sql download 2014]
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Visual Studio(Also known as SSDT or BIDS) to build reports. Check if that is installed.